# basic regex operations in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm following a tutorial about regular expression. I'm getting an error when doing the following:

```
regex = r'(+|-)?\d*\.?\d*'
```

Apparently, Python doesn't like (+|-). What could be the problem?
Also, what could be the issue with not adding r ahead of the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `+` in regular expressions to get a literal `+`, because it usually means "one or more instances of something":

```
regex = r'(\+|-)?\d*\.?\d*'
```

And `r` makes it a "raw" string. Without the `r`, the regular expression escape sequences will be interpreted as string escape sequences, and they'll cause all sorts of problems. (`\b` being a backspace instead of a word boundary, and that kind of thing.)

Answer (score 3):

`+` is a special character. You can use brackets to specify a range of characters, which is better than using an "or" with the pipe character in this case.:

```
regex = r'([+-])?\d*\.?\d*'
```

Otherwise, you just need to escape it in your original version:

```
regex = r'(\+|-)?\d*\.?\d*'
```

Using the `r` is the preferred way of specifying a regex string in python because it indicates a raw string, which should not be interpreted and reduces the amount of escaping you must perform with backslashes. It is just a python regex idiom you will see everywhere.

```
r'(\+|-)?\d*\.?\d*'
#'(\\+|-)?\\d*\\.?\\d*'
```